# Open a non-bootstrap modal (popup dialog/modal) prompted by multiple buttons with same class names generated from a while loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, modal-dialog

```js
var editModal = document.getElementById("editSemModal");
        var editBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("semEditBtn");
        var editSpan = document.getElementsByClassName("editClose")[0];
        var editCancelbtn = document.getElementById("editCancel-btn");

        for (var i = 0; i < editBtn.length; i++) {
            editBtn[i].onclick = function() {
                editModal.style.display = "block";
            }
        }

        editBtn.onclick = function() {
          editModal.style.display = "block";
        }
        
        editSpan.onclick = function() {
          editModal.style.display = "none";
        }

        editCancelbtn.onclick = function() {
          editModal.style.display = "none";
        }



        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
        //this is for my working modal that is not included in this question
            if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
          }
          // this is the modal im having problems with
          else if (event.target == editModal) {
            editModal.style.display = "none";
          }
        }
```

```html
<div class="semester-info">
     <div id="addSemModal" class="modal">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <h2>Semester Information</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="post">
                <table style="width: 60%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>SEMESTER YEAR</td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="semYear" id="semYear">
                                    <option value="<?php ?>"><?php ?></option>
                                    <option value="Y1">Year 1</option>
                                    <option value="Y2">Year 2</option>
                                    <option value="Y3">Year 3</option>
                                    <option value="Y4">Year 4</option>
                                    <option value="Y5">Year 5</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>SEMESTER NUMBER</td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="semNumber" id="semNumber">
                                    <option value="<?php ?>"><?php ?></option>
                                    <option value="S1">Sem 1</option>
                                    <option value="S2">Sem 2</option>
                                    <option value="S3">Sem 3</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>                         
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>SEMESTER MONTH</td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="semMonth" id="semMonth">
                                    <option value="<?php ?>"><?php ?></option>
                                    <option value="January">January</option>
                                    <option value="May">May</option>
                                    <option value="October">October</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>SEMESTER CURRENT YEAR</td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="semCurrentYear" min="2019" max="2099" placeholder="2020" value="<?php ?>"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>SEMESTER DESCRIPTION</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="semDesc" maxlength="55"  value="<?php ?>"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" id="save-btn" value="Save">
                <button id="cancel-btn">Cancel</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>


    <div class="sems" id="sems">
                        <?php
                        $semester = new Semester();
                        $query = "select * from semester where userid = '$userid'";
        
                        $DB = new Database();
                        $conn = $DB->connect();
                        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    
                        //check if no rows returned
                        if ($num_rows != 0){
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        ?> 
                                <a href="">
                                    <div class="sem">
                                        <button type="button" id="semEditBtn" class="semEditBtn">Edit</button>
                                        <h2 class="semH2"> <?php echo $row['semYear'] . $row['semNumber']; ?> </h2>
                                        <h4 class="semH4"> <?php echo $row['semMonth'] . " " . $row['semCurrentYear']; ?> </h4><br>
                                        <div class="sem-container">
                                            <div class="percent">
                                                <div class="skills" style="width: 20%; background-color: #41B3A3;"></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="progress-percent">
                                                <p>20%</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <p> <?php echo $row['semDesc']; ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                </a>   
                                <?php
                        }      
                    }
                
                    //no semesters created error message
                    else {
                        echo "<h3 class='addSemErrorMsg' style='text-align: center; font-weight:500; font-size: 18px; margin-top:150px;'>No semesters created yet!<h3>";
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
```

In my project, my goal is to create a brand new semester div for every row that it retrieves from the database when a user clicks the "Add Semester" button. I have done everything up to this part.

My issue right now is when i click the "Edit" button for each semester div i made, i want a non-bootstrap modal to pop up and enable the user to edit and update the previous semester information that they put.

Right now, my issue is whenever i click the "Edit" button on each semester div, the popup modal shows up for about a split second and never stays on the screen.

Finding some solutions online, i came across CRUD. However, most tutorials on the internet on performing the CRUD Edit is on a Bootstrap modal. Also, i have not come across any tutorial that creates a brand new div for every row returned (its always just in tables).

The sole reason that i refuse to use a Bootstrap modal is because of its design and it somehow disrupts my website's overall layout (even after placing the Bootstrap CDN link before my own stylesheet link). By any chance, is there a way for me to pull this off without using a Bootstrap modal?

I got the CSS/JS Modal from here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Comment: We need context code I think. Many used DOM object are not shown.

Comment: @hogren Noted. I edited the modal i was having troubles with. Would that be enough?